# Why are args being splitted by '=' when terraform is ran from python subprocess

Tags: python, terraform

I have a Python wrapper for terraform, terraform will somehow misinterpret the arguments that it's being passed. Any ideas how to workaround this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

args_echo = ["/bin/echo", "/home/vmindru/proj/tera/terraform",
             "plan",
             "-var foo=bar"]
args_terr = ["/home/vmindru/proj/tera/terraform",
             "plan",
             "-no-color",
             "-var foo=bar"]
echo = subprocess.call(args_echo)
terr = subprocess.call(args_terr)

print echo, terr
```

__Note: __ ass observed below when running simple echo ( or any other binary) it would interpret correctly all the args, for some reason terraform decided to split the arg -var foo=bar into -var foo and probably bar

```
vmindru@vmhodesk:/tmp/test2$ ./test.py 
/home/vmindru/proj/tera/terraform plan -var foo=bar
flag provided but not defined: -var foo
Usage: terraform plan [options] [dir]

  Generates an execution plan for Terraform.

  This execution plan can be reviewed prior to running apply to get a
  sense for what Terraform will do. Optionally, the plan can be saved to
  a Terraform plan file, and apply can take this plan file to execute
  this plan exactly.

Options:

  -backup=path        Path to backup the existing state file before
                      modifying. Defaults to the "-state-out" path with
                      ".backup" extension. Set to "-" to disable backup.

  -destroy            If set, a plan will be generated to destroy all resources
                      managed by the given configuration and state.

  -detailed-exitcode  Return detailed exit codes when the command exits. This
                      will change the meaning of exit codes to:
                      0 - Succeeded, diff is empty (no changes)
                      1 - Errored
                      2 - Succeeded, there is a diff

  -input=true         Ask for input for variables if not directly set.

  -module-depth=n     Specifies the depth of modules to show in the output.
                      This does not affect the plan itself, only the output
                      shown. By default, this is -1, which will expand all.

  -no-color           If specified, output won't contain any color.

  -out=path           Write a plan file to the given path. This can be used as
                      input to the "apply" command.

  -parallelism=n      Limit the number of concurrent operations. Defaults to 10.

  -refresh=true       Update state prior to checking for differences.

  -state=statefile    Path to a Terraform state file to use to look
                      up Terraform-managed resources. By default it will
                      use the state "terraform.tfstate" if it exists.

  -target=resource    Resource to target. Operation will be limited to this
                      resource and its dependencies. This flag can be used
                      multiple times.

  -var 'foo=bar'      Set a variable in the Terraform configuration. This
                      flag can be set multiple times.

  -var-file=foo       Set variables in the Terraform configuration from
                      a file. If "terraform.tfvars" is present, it will be
                      automatically loaded if this flag is not specified.
0 1
vmindru@vmhodesk:/tmp/test2$
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be `-foo=bar`

Comment: Have you tried something like `"-var", "'foo=bar'"`?

Comment: As nightuser points out and TF clearly states in the output above you need to surround the var definition with quotes

Comment: can you show the output when running with quotes around the var definition?

Comment: @nightuser - separating those did the trick, simply surounding with quotes does not help though.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR  http://pastebin.com/BfhLSaJC

Comment: @VeaceslavMindru, so, have you solved your problem?

Comment: @nightuser yes thank you ! at least it's not erroring on what it was so far.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR and nightuser thanks, guys!

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you can post your solution as answer and mark it accepted. Someone else could find your problem (and solution) useful.

Answer (score 3):

*Making a note of this for easy finding in the future though full credit goes to @nightuser for their answer in the question comments.*

The Python `subprocess.call()` function expects no spaces to be present in the arguments and any spaces should be separate elements in the list.

In this case:

```
args_echo = ["/bin/echo", "/home/vmindru/proj/tera/terraform",
             "plan",
             "-var foo=bar"]
```

becomes:

```
args_echo = ["/bin/echo", "/home/vmindru/proj/tera/terraform",
             "plan",
             "-var",
             "foo=bar"]
```